# Classification of algebras (associative, commutative, idempotent)

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is there a classification of algebras according to the type of operations they have? Ideally I want to know if there is a list which says which algebras (any we can think of) have operations that are associative, commutative and idempotent.

It can be any kind of algebra we can think of (I doubt the list is big, and I assume there will be algebra isomorphisms relating some of them).

If such a classification does not exist, is there some way to obtain information in this direction?

Comment: How many algebras exist out there?

Comment: Is this supposed to mock my question?

Comment: Yes and no. It looks really difficult to classificate *all* algebras and to say which are boolean in this list: think about the classification of simple finite groups...

Comment: Yes, this I know it’s difficult but I don’t know if there exists partial classification or equivalent. This is why I ask further info.

Comment: What you are looking for is Universal Algebra; algebras are classified first by **type**: the "number" of operations, and the arity of the relevant operations. Secondarily, given a type, you may also add **identities** that the operations must satisfy; associativity, commutativity, and idempotency are examples of identities on operations. The class of all algebras of a given type that satisfy a given set of identities is called a **variety** of algebras. The list is not just "big", it is **enormous**. There are uncountably many varieties of groups, for instance.

Comment: Is [this](http://irma.math.unistra.fr/~loday/PAPERS/EncyclopALG2010WSfinal.pdf) something you're looking for?

Comment: What do you mean by "algebra", exactly?  Arturo Magidin's answer is a good answer to one interpretation of your question but it's possible you have something totally different in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*"I doubt the list is big."*

That, I'm afraid, is quite wrong.

What you are straining for is **Universal Algebra**, which seeks to study the general features of algebras.

Given a set $X$, and a nonnegative integer $n$, an **$n$-ary operation on $X$** is a function $X^n\to X$. You can also have infinitary operations, where you take an infinite ordinal $\alpha$ and consider a function $X^{\alpha}\to X$.  Given an operation $f$ on $X$, its *arity* is the $n$ such that $f$ is a function from $X^n$ to $X$. So the arity of addition in $\mathbb{R}$ is $2$, for example, since it is a function $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$, mapping $(a,b)$ to $a+b$.

A **type** is an ordered pair $(\Omega, \mathrm{ari}_{\Omega})$, where $\Omega$ is a set, and $\mathrm{ari}_{\Omega}$ is a map from $\Omega$ to the ordinals. The elements of $\Omega$ are the *operation symbols*, and the ordinal $\mathrm{ari}_{\omega}(s)$ is the *arity of $s$* for each $s\in \Omega$.

If $(\Omega,\mathrm{ari}_{\Omega})$ is a type, then an **algebra of type $\Omega$** is a pair $(A, (s_A)_{s\in\Omega})$, where $A$ is a set, and for each $s\in \Omega$, $s_A$ is an $\mathrm{ari}_{\Omega}(s)$-ary operation on $A$.

For instance, a type $(\{+\},\mathrm{ari})$, with $\mathrm{ari}(+)=2$ defines algebras that consist of a set with a binary operation.

Once you have a type, you can impose **identities**. For instance, in an algebra as above, you can impose the condition that $+(+(a,b),c) = +(a,+(b,c))$, which is associativity, etc.

The collection of all algebras of given type $(\Omega,\mathrm{ari}_{\Omega})$ form a category. The collection of all algebras of a given type that satisfy a given set of identities is called a **variety of ($\Omega$-)algebras**.  The study of varieties of algebras is one of the main concerns of Universal Algebra.

There are too many of them to discuss individually. In fact, if you just consider how many classes of **groups** there are that satisfy certain sets of identities, the answer is **uncountably many** (there are uncountably many varieties of groups); in fact, there are uncountably many varieties of *solvable groups* (though only countably many varieties of abelian groups).

I recommend George Bergman's **An Invitation to General Algebra and Universal Constructions**, Springer Verlag Universitext; or Ralph McKenzie, George McNulty, and Walter Taylor's *Algebras, Lattices, Varieties volume 1*, Wadsworth and Brooks/Cole; or George Gratzer's *Universal Algebra*, Springer Verlag.

Comment: *though only countably many varieties of abelian groups* - wow, why does this happen?

Comment: @lisyarus: Because group identities are equivalent to commutator identities and power identities, and all commutator identities are satisfied by abelian groups. So the only varieties of abelian groups are "all abelian groups", and "all abelian groups of exponent $n$", with $n$ a positive integer.

Comment: Is this variety anyhow related to the varieties that we learn about in algebraic geometry?

Comment: @Marion: No, they are not; just like normal subgroups are not related in any way to the normal distributions you learn about in statistics. Just a coincidence of terminology.